# ASP.net - ValidationSummary output to pop-up page - or as plain html onto the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.net page with asp validators and afew custom validators.

When I click submit on the page I want to put the output of the Validation summary on to a new page(pop-up) and leave the old page in the background.

OR

put the validation summary in plain html on the same page

Is it possible to do this?

Any and all help will be usfull.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaScript - window.onload - put content of a <div></div> onto a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266380/javascript-window-onload-put-content-of-a-div-div-onto-a-new-window)

This is what i used in the end, but i directed the output to a alert box rather than a pop up.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="MyValidationSummary" runat="server"
                       ShowMessageBox="true"
                       ShowSummary="false" />
```

I'm using the .NET Framework 3.5.

Hope this helps.

CD

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you wanted to with the ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopup control- [see here for an example](http://ashishware.com/ASPValid.shtml).

I certainly don't recommend doing it with a real page (ie new web browser window) if you really wish to have this functionality. Personally I would not do it this way anyway- as having to keep dismissing a dialog would quickly get frustrating for a user.

Comment: It is due to accessibility with screen readers in the organisation, the screen reader wont read the validation summary since it is genarated via js

Comment: The JS can be used to simply control the visibility of the content (as opposed to generating it or requesting it with AJAX), so the screen reader should have no problem.

Comment: the screen reader wont read the error since the errors are in js var's in the code. The reader only reads the HTML

Comment: At the cost of degrading the user experience for everyone else, you could use EnableClientScript = False on the validator controls. I think that would be more preferable to a popup.