# How to dispay a page in another domain into my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

In angular 7 i have created a dummy page , http://localhost:4200/auth/register.

Here i need to display that page **http://localhost:4200/auth/register** in different domain using jquery,either using load() or other possible methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery load() Demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $( "#box" ).load( "http://localhost:4200/auth/register", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <h2>Click button to load new content inside DIV box</h2>
    </div>
    <button type="button">Load Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors you getting?

Comment: If I understood your question right, iFrame can be used to display different domain pages in your website. If its in differnt domain, which you dont have any control over, you can not manage with javascript

Comment: if the other domain allows your domain in their CORS policies than you can load content from other domain with proper authentication values, otherwise as @AnuragR mentioned, use `IFrames` to load.

Comment: for some reasons (based on requirement) iFrame cant be used and embed,Object is not supporting in IE11  @AnuragR

Answer (score 0):

you can use [HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) with 
[DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Comment: for some reasons (based on requirement) iFrame cant be used and embed,Object is not supporting in IE11

Comment: try to use [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1266415/12555084) it look's like what you need `window.open("url");` see more on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: it's opening in a new window , i need to open in a page within a div. " @Karim SNOUSSI